# ExactTarget Fuel REST API Update Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am a little confused by the Fuel REST API. It would seem that you cannot do an update by the subscriberKey. This would seem to be a pretty basic operation or am I missing something? I'm using the .Net SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribers are updated with the C-Sharp SDK like this -

```
ET_Subscriber patchSub = new ET_Subscriber();
            patchSub.AuthStub = myclient;
            patchSub.EmailAddress = SubscriberTestEmail;
            patchSub.Status = SubscriberStatus.Unsubscribed;
            patchSub.Attributes = new FuelSDK.ET_ProfileAttribute[] { new ET_ProfileAttribute() { Name = "First Name", Value = "ExactTarget Example" } };
            PatchReturn pathResponse = patchSub.Patch();
```

You can see the full sample here - https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/Dot9/objsamples/Sample_Subscriber.cs

Comment: Is there a REST API resource for this operation?